# When trying to insert data in Mongo, it showing the error can't have . in field names [H_GS165L15.1] :

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to insert 7000 key-value pair in a document in MongoDB. But i found the below mention error:

```
 **[main] Error: can't have . in field names [H_GS165L15.1] :
DBCollection.prototype._validateForStorage@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:244:1
Bulk/this.insert@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:663:17
DBCollection.prototype.insert@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:349:13**
```

The collection looks like:

```
db.collectionname.insert(
     {
        "GABR": 170,
        "OD": 69.4,
        "GS3": 20.7,
        "SE3C": 97.1,
         ...
         ...
         ...
         >7000 key-value pair
    }
```

);

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because one or more of your >7000 keys contains '.' character in name. For example, "my.key" is invalid field in MongoDB as it contains '.' character.

As per MongoDB, you cannot use '.' character inside field names. Also field names cannot start with '$' character.

Apart from these two constraints you can use any UTF8 character in field name.